# SharePoint Authenticate.aspx Redirect Not Working

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am creating an Application that uses Azure AD and SharePoint Online.

I am authenticating with Azure AD perfectly using the ClientID and the ClientSecret. I have also configured the Azure AD Application to allow full access to SharePoint.

So far so good.

I log into my application and I retrieve a SharePoint Authorization Token using my existing Azure AD Token and I retrieve various list items (SERVER SIDE) from a couple of different lists.

So far so good.

Some list items have an Image Url that I put into the HTML page. This is a url that looks like this: `xxxxx.sharepoint.com/ImageLibrary/Image.jpg`

This is where my problem is.

I do not have a cookie that can authenticate to `xxxxx.sharepoint.com` so when I request the image at `xxxxx.sharepoint.com` it fails.

If I request the image directly by going to `xxxxx.sharepoint.com/ImageLibrary/Image.jpg` in my browser address bar it works just fine. (It performs two 302 redirects, hits `login.microsoftonline.com` bounces back to sharepoint and then eventually I get the image as well as the FedAuth token).

So I had a solution, what If I obtain the cookie from `xxxxx.sharepoint.com` by going to `xxxxx.sharepoint.com/_layouts/Authenticate.aspx?Source=MyCustomSite.com`

Herein lies the problem.

The Authenticate.aspx page does not allow redirects from untrusted sites. I think it's using the method `SPUtility.Redirect` with the `SPRedirectFlags.Trusted` flag.

My question is: How can I add MyCustomSite.com to SharePoint Online's trusted site redirect list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out!

It looks like **Authenticate.aspx** isn't designed for the purpose I had intended for with SharePoint Online. SharePoint Online wants you to use SharePoint Add-Ins instead.

So all I had to do was register an app and use the AppRedirect.aspx page to do the redirect.

To register an app simply go to: `xxxxx.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/AppRegNew.aspx`

- Click the Generate button next to the Client ID (copy the Client ID to use later)
- Click the Generate button next to the Client Secret
- The title is just a name for the Application
- The app domain is the domain for where you want to redirect to
- and the most important field is the Redirect URI, this is the url of where you want to redirect to

Once you have the app registered you can redirect users by going to:

```
https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appredirect.aspx?client_id=00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000&redirect_uri=https://MyCoolApp.net
```

The `redirect_uri` parameter must match the URI entered into the AppRegNew.aspx form or SharePoint will display a **"Are you sure you want to go to this site"** page when the redirect occurs.